# How much space takes to install a physical copy of Pikmin 3 on Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, pikmin-3

How much space takes to install a physical copy of Pikmin 3 on Wii U? With, and without the DLCs? (and needed to complete the full game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2013/06/pikmin_3_will_need_to_gather_3950mb_to_download_onto_your_wii_u) it uses 31,840 blocks, which is almost 4GB. This is the base game. I did not find anything for the individual DLC packages.

Comment: Thank you, that is still a lot for the game, but are most of Wii U games just like that?

Comment: @Beavoru some are even heavier than this. See a list here to get an idea: https://www.destructoid.com/the-destructoid-wii-u-game-file-size-guide-291062.phtml

Comment: And this is ONLY for the physical/boxed version right? because, i thought if i get this game i shouldnt need to install that much GB